# problem with a recursive function code for beginners

Tags: python, recursion

I'm currently learning about recursive functions on Python. So far I've solved this task:

A gold coin is placed in the safe and the safe is closed. The safe is then placed in another, larger safe and another gold coin is added. The second safe is placed in a third, even bigger safe, adding two more gold coins, etc. So with the first safe, 1 gold coin is placed in the next, with the second 2 gold coins, with the third 3 gold coins, etc.

Create a recursive function that takes the sequence number of the safe as an argument and returns the total number of gold coins hidden in this safe.
`

```
def gold(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return gold(n-1)+(n-1)
```

`

Now, I need to write a code where the number of coins increases like this: when n equals 1, return value is 2; when n equals 2, return value is 3; when n equals 3, return value is 4; when n equals 4, return value is 6; when n equals 5, return value is 7; when n equals 6, return value is 8; when n equals 7, return value is 10 and so on (the number of coins increases by 1 every time, except when n = 4, 7, 10, 13... where it increases by 2).
For example, the code should return these values:

```
>>> gold(7)
10
>>> gold(8)
11
```

So far I've only got this:

```
def gold(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 2
    else:
```

How can I do so that usually the number of gold coins is increased by one coin but every 4th, 7th, 10th, ...etc it increases by two? I know this is probably a very easy and stupid question, but I can't figure it out

Answer (score 1):

This code does what you want (you just have to test whether n == 4, 7, 10..., that is n == 3k+1, in other words, n modulo 3 == 1):

```
def gold(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 2
    if n%3 == 1: # if n == 3k+1, so for n = 4, 7, 10 ...
        return 2 + gold(n-1)
    return 1 + gold(n-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Look according to your explanation every 4th, 7th and 10th ... safe should be added with **TWO** coins, so we can check so with a condition :

```
if n % 3 == 1:
  return 2 + gold(n-1)
```

and in addition to my answer according to your explanation **The First Safe will have two coins in it ...** and hence the base/stop case will have the condition :

```
if n == 1:
  return 2
```

So, the final recursive function will be :

```
def gold(n):
  if n == 1:
    return 2
  elif n % 3 == 1:
    return 2 + gold(n-1)
  else:
    return 1 + gold(n-1)
```

and the Output will be of your desire :

```
>>> gold(7)
10
>>> gold(8)
11
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want

```
def gold(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    if (n - 1) % 3 == 0:
        return 2 + gold(n-1)
    else:
        return 1 + gold(n-1)
```

Comment: when n equals 1, it doesn't seem to make sense that the return value is 2

Comment: the code has to return it like that: when n equals 1, return value is 2; when n equals 2, return value is 3; when n equals 3, return value is 4; when n equals 4, return value is 6; when n equals 5, return value is 7; when n equals 6, return value is 8; when n equals 7, return value is 10 and so on

Comment: This doesn't quite match your question; if I understand correctly, you put **2 golds in the 1st safe**, then 1 more, 1 more, 2 more ...

Answer (score -1):

You probabbly wants something like this:

**Edited**:

```
def gold(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    elif n == 2:
        return 2
    elif n % 2 == 0:
        return gold(n-1) + 1
    else:
        return gold(n-1) + 2
```

Comment: `gold(7) ->10`  in your code `gold(7)->21`..

Comment: Sorry, your explanation is a little strange but I got it. I edit the answer

Comment: the code has to return it like that: when n equals 1, return value is 2; when n equals 2, return value is 3; when n equals 3, return value is 4; when n equals 4, return value is 6; when n equals 5, return value is 7; when n equals 6, return value is 8; when n equals 7, return value is 10 and so on

Comment: this recursive progression does not make sense, make sure that this is the desired result.